# Using OR conditions in meta_query for query_posts argument

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, sql, advanced-custom-fields

I have searched high and low for this but I cant seem to locate anything.

I am trying to filter some results and when I make an args array like this and pass it to query_posts I noticed that the generated SQL uses AND instead of OR for the 'class_1_days' value.  I would like to make than an OR.  How would I go about doing this?  (I am using LIKE there as the data is serialized, otherwise I would have tried an "IN" and pass an array.  What is the proper way to go about this?

```
$args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'courses', 
            'term' => 'drawing', 
            'post_type' => 'school', 
            'paged' => $paged,
            'meta_query' =>
                #$checkbox_array,
                array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'instructor',
                        'value' => '1128',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'class_1_days',
                        'value' => 'Friday',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'class_1_days',
                        'value' => 'Saturday',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                )

        );
```

This is the relevant SQL that is being generated where I noticed the AND

```
[138] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN     wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN     wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND (     wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (18) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'school' AND     (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (     (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'instructor' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%1128%')
AND  (mt1.meta_key = 'class_1_days' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%Friday%')
AND  (mt2.meta_key = 'class_1_days' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%Saturday%') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `'relation' => 'OR'` [as in the Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) below:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR', /* <-- here */
        array(
            'key' => 'color',
            'value' => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That will give you an `OR` across all of your meta_query blocks. If what you need is something like `WHERE "instructor" = 1128 AND (class_1_days = "value1" OR class_1_days = "value2")` then something like this would do it if your data wasn't serialized.

```
$args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'courses', 
        'term' => 'drawing', 
        'post_type' => 'school', 
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' =>
            array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'instructor',
                    'value' => '1128',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'class_1_days',
                    'value' => array('Friday','Saturday')
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                )
            )

    );
```

Given that you have serialized data this is going to be difficult. You could write a filter for `posts_where` but I'd expect the result to inefficient and prone to error.

The correct approach for cases like this where you need to search/filter/sort by some piece of information is, in my experience, to not store your data as a serialized array in the first place. That is simply the wrong approach if you need queries like this.

If I were taking over this project I would loop through the data that needs to be queried in this way and re-save each piece at a key/value pair. The parts you are not querying can stay serialized. There is no (good) way to do this in MySQL with MySQL functions either as part of the query you are attempting or as some stand-alone query. I have seen attempts at creating a MySQL "unserialize" function but I don't see the point. Re-saving the data is the way to go.

It should be a fairly simple query to get all of the `class_1_days` data. Then loop over it and save the parts you need to query as independent keys and put the rest back as serialized data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.   Is there a way I can do an AND or?  I am trying to Keep the instructor bit.  Your example makes them all OR.  I just need the class_1_days bit to be an or.  Similar to if I had it as 'value' => array(bla,bla,bla), 'compare' => IN


Basically where Instructor = 'bla' AND value IN (bla,bla,bla)

Comment: Thanks @S_ha_dam.  Is there a way I can unserialze the DB.  This is something I took on second hand so I dont know what all that will effect.  I saw a link to an app that did just that, however the link to it was broken.

Comment: Thanks, however simply resaving it wont work this is a live environment where this data is constantly being saved and the class_1_data is only part of the equation.  There are multiple ones class_0_data, class_2_data, etc and so on and so forth, and those are added by the users.  I think the best approach may be to backtrack and find a way to reinstall the module and make it so that it doesnt save serialized (if i figure out how) and go from there X-( ... I didn't mention the other classes portion cuz I figured I could figure it out on my own

Comment: You certainly will have to refactor the "save" function but will need to resave the existing data as well or you will end up with a weird mix of serialized and not-serialized. Get the code working on a dev server then put the live one in maintenance mode for twenty minutes at some low-traffic time of day.

Comment: Oh yes certainly I will have to change the current data!

this blows.  I thought this was going to be an easy fix ugh!

Comment: wait...how about this...is there a way I can tack on AFTER this filter another filter which would be by instructor?

Or even get back the direct php array that wordpress is using and edit that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the last question but via filters you can alter the query to be just about anything you want. By "tacking on" something, I doubt you will end up with an efficient query though.

Comment: uh, like say you know in php you would have your actual array as classes[1][bla],classes[2][bla] etc etc, if I knew that that actual array is called I could potentially just do some PHP array searching and regex and filter it on my own after i already got the desired results from the OR statement that you provided earlier.

Comment: Yes, that is possible but you'd have to pull everything and then sort it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the WordPress codex nested arrays can be used to construct complex queries. In your example your need something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'courses', 
    'term' => 'drawing', 
    'post_type' => 'school', 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' =>
        array(
           'relation' => 'AND', // default relation
            array(
                'key' => 'instructor',
                'value' => '1128',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'class_1_days',
                    'value' => 'Friday',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'class_1_days',
                    'value' => 'Saturday',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            )
        )
);
```