# Filtering custom posts by custom fields (ACF)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query, search

I'm working on a site with photo contests. Each contest has a lot of additional info, which I store in custom fields (thanks to Advanced Custom Fields). Now I want to search through contests filtering them based on some custom fields values.

My `function.php` file looks like this:

```
// Custom Post Search
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    // validate
    if( is_admin() )
    {
        return;
    }

    if( !$query->is_main_query() )
    {
        return;
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['fee']) )
    {
        $contestFee = explode(',', $_GET['fee']);

        $contestFeeArray = array(
            'key'       => 'fee',
            'value'     => $contestFee,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
    }
    if( !empty($_GET['theme']) )
    {
        $contestTheme = explode(',', $_GET['theme']);

        $contestThemeArray = array(
            'key'       => 'theme',
            'value'     => $contestTheme,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
    }

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $contestThemeArray,
        $contestFeeArray,
    );

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return;

}
?>
```

Now I'm quering my search like this `website.com/contests/?fee=free&theme=landscape` and here's the problem. If I query only `fee` value everything works perfectly. But when I want to query `theme` value nothing is displayed.

I'm pasting also arrays displayed through `get_field_object` (which is an Advanced Custom Fields' function):

`fee` custom field

```
Array ( [ID] => 136 [key] => field_553bee3a1f8ff [label] => Is contest paid or free? [name] => fee [prefix] => [type] => radio [value] => free [menu_order] => 7 [instructions] => [required] => 1 [id] => [class] => [conditional_logic] => 0 [parent] => 8 [wrapper] => Array ( [width] => [class] => [id] => ) [_name] => fee [_input] => [_valid] => 1 [choices] => Array ( [free] => Free [paid] => Paid ) [other_choice] => 0 [save_other_choice] => 0 [default_value] => free [layout] => vertical )
```

`theme` custom field

```
Array ( [ID] => 23 [key] => field_5523fed672b4b [label] => Theme [name] => theme [prefix] => [type] => select [value] => Array ( [0] => nude [1] => people [2] => fine-art ) [menu_order] => 12 [instructions] => [required] => 1 [id] => [class] => [conditional_logic] => 0 [parent] => 8 [wrapper] => Array ( [width] => [class] => [id] => ) [_name] => theme [_input] => [_valid] => 1 [choices] => Array ( [aerial] => Aerial [fine-art] => Fine Art [landscape] => Landscape [nature] => Nature [nude] => Nude [people] => People [wildlife] => Wildlife ) [default_value] => Array ( [] => ) [allow_null] => 0 [multiple] => 1 [ui] => 1 [ajax] => 1 [placeholder] => [disabled] => 0 [readonly] => 0 )
```

**So to wrap it up** - I want to query custom posts (contests) search through `website.com/contests/?fee=free&theme=landscape` and in this case display contest that are free AND have landscape theme.

I can't find out what's wrong with my code. Do you have any ideas on making this work?

Thanks!

Comment: `theme` is already a WordPress query var, use something more unique.

Comment: I've changed it to `contest_theme` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Milo you can check out the site here - (http://patryk.me/guru/contests/)

Comment: @Milo Ok, I've finally got it, but still have a little problem. ACF postmeta which can have multiple values are stored in MySQL like this: `a:1:{i:0;s:9:"Landscape";}` or `a:5:{i:0;s:6:"Aerial";i:1;s:6:"Nature";i:2;s:4:"Nude";i:3;s:6:"People";i:4;s:8:"Wildlife";}`. The problem that remains is how to query `contest_theme` with multiple values (like "Nature", "Nude", etc.)

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104062/21376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after deeper research I've found out that values of some custom fields created by ACF are stored in MySQL database with some additional information like `a:5:{i:0;s:6:"Aerial";i:1;s:6:"Nature";i:2;s:4:"Nude";i:3;s:6:"People";i:4;s:8:‌​"Wildlife";}`. This happens when a custom field can store multiple values (like chechboxes).

So I've edited part of my query from this:
    if( !empty($_GET['theme']) )
    {
        $contestTheme = explode(',', $_GET['theme']);

```
    $contestThemeArray = array(
        'key'       => 'theme',
        'value'     => $contestTheme,
        'compare'   => 'IN',
    );
}
```

To this:

```
if( !empty($_GET['contest_theme']) )
{
    $contestTheme = explode(',', $_GET['contest_theme']);
    $contestThemeArray = array('relation' => 'OR');
    foreach ($contestTheme as $theme) {
        $contestThemeArray[] = array(
            'key'       => 'contest_theme',
            'value'     => $theme,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

}
```