# WP_Query with LIKE returns strange query

Tags: mysql

IN works quite fine for comparison though

```
   array(

                    'key' => 'customdata',

                    'value' => $arraydata,

                    'compare' => 'IN'

                ),
```

but when i try below with LIKE it returns strange result with long codes and also no record is found against it. Any help much appreicated

```
   array(

                    'key' => 'customdata',

                    'value' => $arraydata,

                    'compare' => 'LIKE'

                )

$loop = new WP_Query($loopArray);
echo "Query: {$loop->request}";
```

Comment: What is inside `$arraydata`? `LIKE` is used to compare strings. What values are you hoping to match with an array by using `LIKE`? Do you want to check `LIKE` for each element in the array?

Comment: PS: The strange long codes are normal. They are placeholders for `%`. See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303935/wpdb-prepare-like-placeholders/303944

Comment: But it should return the result. I can get correct result through IN comparison operator where as LIKE is not returning any result though i have the data which is why IN brings exact matched values. Below is the full array code:

$loopArray['meta_query'][] = array('relation'    => 'OR',array('key' => 'customdata1','value' => 'MyVal1','compare' => 'LIKE'),array('key' => 'customdata2','value' => 'MyVal2','compare' => 'LIKE'));

Comment: `IN` is for checking if a value is in an array. `LIKE` is for comparing strings. They are for different things. You can't just use them interchangeably. You've ignored my question: What is inside the `$arraydata` variable? Is it a string, or an array?

Comment: Sorry Jacob inside array variable there are values like Deen in my below query:

After tweak i am getting all possible records now regardless of my keyword. Is there anything wrong i am doing: 

( mt5.meta_key = 'pr' AND mt5.meta_value LIKE '{6998fadab679fa902a65bccda33565e90707e29805a823569989b7f24beab57b}{6998fadab679fa902a65bccda33565e90707e29805a823569989b7f24beab57b}' ) ) ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'lists' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID

Comment: I am trying to explain the problem, but you're ignoring me. _What is inside `$arraydata`?_

Comment: $arraydata contains only one value i am looking to compare such as $arraydata='Deen' so that query should return all records having word Deen as Deen1, Deen 2, Deen 3

Comment: The SQL you've shared shows that there is no value. How are you populating `$arraydata`?

Comment: $arraydata has the values and i can see on print_r which i am pasting in next comment

Comment: Array ( [post_type] => lists [post_status] => publish [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => l_status [value] => Sold [compare] => IN )[1] => Array ( [key] => beds [value] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1) [compare] => IN [type] => NUMERIC )[2] => Array ( [key] => price [value] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1000000 )[compare] => BETWEEN [type] => NUMERIC )[3] => Array ( [key] => category [value] => Sold )[4] => Array ( [relation] => OR [0] => Array ( [key] => mp [value] => Array ( [0] => Deema )[compare] => IN )[1] => Array ( [key] => mp [value] => Array ( [0] => Deema )[compare] => LIKE )))

Comment: Don't expect to get much help here if you are not trying to be helpful yourself. You were asked to show code populating `$arraydata` or at least its content. Instead you show query data. It takes time and effort to understand it, and its mostly irrelevant to your problem. Whatever you say, your value **is** array (print_r confirms it), and you can't compare arrays with LIKE. You need to create LIKE conditions for each of your array values and combine them in single meta query using OR.

Comment: I am very sorry if i failed to provide the exact info. Here is my code of populating $arraydata = explode(',', $searchKeywords);

Comment: explode creates array. Array may not be used in LIKE comparison. Use `for` loop on this array to create multiple LIKE conditions for each possible value and combine them in meta_query array with `relation => 'OR'`. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104060/using-or-conditions-in-meta-query-for-query-posts-argument for combined meta_query example.

Comment: Vitauts, Excellent help  and thank you very much for pointing me where is the issue which is fixed now :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `LIKE` to compare arrays. `LIKE` is used to check if a string matches, or partially matches, a value in the database.

`IN` is used to check if a value in the database is in a given set of values.

They are not interchangeable.

The correct comparison to use in your case depends entirely on what data you're using, and what you're trying to do, which is not clear from your question, or comments. But here's some pointers:

- If you want to match a partial *string*, use `LIKE`.
- If you want to match a value in an *array* of values, use `IN`.
- If you want to match values between an *array* of two given values in, use `BETWEEN`.
- If you want to match an exact string or number, use `=`.
- If you want to match *multiple* partial strings in an *array*, you need to split that array into separate `LIKE` queries for each item in the array.

The "strange" query you are seeing is `$wpdb` 'escaping' the `%` placeholders used in `LIKE` queries. This is expected, and is part of a security feature added in 4.8.3. You can learn more at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303935/wpdb-prepare-like-placeholders/303944).

Comment: Jacob, Thank you for the great help , issue is resolved.